# Delphi 2009 can't find record that is declared in a package

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, package

In Delphi 2009 there is a package, that was installed properly, and works.

However when a code compiles it throws an error

```
error E2003: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TSomething'
```

Why and how to fix it? (include the .dcu? the .pas?)

The project is build without "build with runtime packages" option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have forgotten to include the unit that contains the definition of TSomething. Being in a package doesn't mean you don't have to use the units explicitly.

Another possibility is that TSomething is defined in the implementation part of a unit in which case it can't be accessed from outside the unit.

Comment: silly me, forgot to check "uses" for the unit. ERRR if only Delphi gui could have help when i say "this is TSomething"

Comment: @none, you can blame it on the monday ;-).